# Why do we use spinors for describing fermions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, spinors

I.e., what properties of the spinors gives us a reason for using them for describing of wavefunctions of fermions?

Comment: Spinors allow for the correct spin-statistics.

Comment: Aren't spinors also used for Bosons ? (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spinor.html)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bispinor

Comment: Nick: What I think the article means is that spinor notation can be useful in describing bosons. Spinors are like the building blocks of SO(N) representations. You can find the vector representation and other tensorial representations of SO(N) by taking products of spinor representations.

Comment: But using spinors we can get an expression for energy and impulse of the field, which which are alternate in sign. So, the spinor's formalism lead to the anticommutation relations between the operators of the amplitudes and, thereby, to the Fermi-statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're using spinor fields for fermions because Nature does the same. Nature does so because She has no choice. Pauli has proven the spin-statistics theorem that says that all fields whose particles obey the Fermi-Dirac statistics (with the Pauli exclusion principle) have to carry a half-integral spin; and those with the Bose-Einstein statistics have to have an integral spin. Mixing a spin with a wrong statistics or vice versa would lead to negative prrobabilities or energies unbounded from below.

The only half-integer field that doesn't require any gauge symmetry to get rid of the negative-norm states is the spin-1/2 field, the spinor. A spinor may be viewed as an object that is more elementary than a vector and that was previously overlooked. It's also possible to build vectors and tensors out of the spinorial components – vectors and tensors may be represented by spintensors of various sorts. But the word "spinors" should be reserved for the representations with $j=1/2$.

There also exist "unphysical" field theories such as the topological ones that may violate the spin-statistics relations. Also, Faddeev-Popov ghosts used to deal with gauge symmetries in a modern way always violate the spin-statistics relationship – the rule is exactly reverted for them. $b,c$ are fermions with an integer spin for a bosonic symmetry, and $\beta,\gamma$ are bosons with a half-integral spin. They don't create physical particles.